# Error - vbscript run from java code

Tags: java, vbscript

i'm using one vbscript file to convert mass excel files into txt files.It is working fine.

I want to do the same operation through the java code . I'm trying to execute the file from java code like

```
 try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("wscript C:\\Datas\\xl2tab.vbs");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(convertFile.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

I'm getting an error like

[image]

Anyone have an idea to run the script file from java code..?

Comment: Excuse me for stating the obvious:
It **is** running `wscript`, and it **is** running your VBS script.
Within the VBS script it is failing to find the file that it mentions. It fails at line 52. We can't really guess what is going wrong inside the script without a listing&hellip;

Comment: The script is running. Have you looked into the possible causes mentioned in the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the script takes current directory for converting excel files.As i'm running the java code from Netbeans, it takes the netbeans project folder as current directory and trying to convert.

I solved by passing the folder path(where files are placed for conversion) as parameter variable to script.

Now i can run the script from java code.So, it is better to use variables for folder path ..